# php or javascript Auto Print

Tags: php, javascript, printing

I want my application to print directly to the default printer without the Windows select printer dialog coming up and
I really dont need to display the screen. All the user wants is a printout, receipt.

Comment: If javascript was allowed to do that, I would be worried.

Comment: Have u got any solution here? I want to make the webpage also print invoices automatically.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do it.
You can only do `window.print()` with javascript and it displays the window.

Why you cannot: because safety.

Answer (score 1):

No I'm afraid this is not possible. You could just run millions of print tasks at the time, and it wouldn't be good for user

Comment: i want when the page refresh the code in php chack the row in database, if database not empty the code will print just 1 page

for example : invoice.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. In Firefox about:config you can make property print.always_print_silent equal to true.Then Firefox will print without prompt.
And using "JS Print setup" you can adjust some printer parameters directly from javascript

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't do that with JavaScript.